# JSF not recognizing a bean with @Named and @SessionScoped annotations

Tags: jsf, cdi, managed-bean

According to the tutorial found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-configure001.htm#GIRCR ,
a class annotated with `@Named` and a scope annotation is automatically registered as a CDI bean by the JSF application. However, whenever the bean is invoked on a particular request in my application, I get this error:

`Target Unreachable, identifier 'query' resolved to null] with root cause
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, identifier 'query' resolved to null`

This is the class that I have:

```
package beans;

import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Query {

    private String name;

    public Query() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

What could I be doing wrong? Here are the maven dependencies I'm using:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I replace the `@Named` annotation with `@ManagedBean`, everything works and the bean is registered fine. But with the Java EE 7 specification, I should be able to use the `@Named` annotation right?

Comment: You should use javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped with @Named

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Why don't you share the full stacktrace.